# How to write Linq to Sql query for geting table with condition from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB.I am unable to write Linq to Sql query.

How to write retrieve table from MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

I like what Christian says, but I think it is clear that the NORM project is dead at this point (though the source is out there freely so that could always change).  For a nice LINQ interface over Mongo take a look at [Fluent Mongo](https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo).  Thus far I have found it to be a good experience. Interestingly the CodeProject article that gideon mentions is by the same fellow behind the Fluent Mongo lib but I can not find it mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much too about mongoDb, but I do know the Database is under the **NoSQL** category and linq-to-sql doesn't make much sense.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Document_store

Scan through these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb+linq

**Linq** is supported, see these articles:
http://wekeroad.com/2010/03/04/using-mongo-with-linq/
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/MongoDBCS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use LINQ-to-SQL with MongoDB on the backend, since Mongo does not use/accept/understand SQL. You can however use LINQ, if for instance you use [NORM](https://github.com/atheken/NoRM/) library for MongoDB.

If you are specifically after LINQ, but just a nice fluent query interface the [official C# MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center) driver from 10Gen has really nice and accesible [query interface](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-MongoCollection%3CTDefaultDocument%3Eclass).